# On Le Chatelier's principle

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics

According to my textbook,

> Increasing the concentration of the reactants increases the rate of forward reaction only to reestablish equilibrium (Le Chatelier's principle)

But doesn't that also increase the rate of the backwards reaction as products are produced?

Comment: It does, to an extent. As both rates become equal again, the new equilibrium is established.

Comment: Yes, and both product and reactant concentrations are higher at the new equilibrium concentrations.  That means that both the forward and reverse reaction rates are higher at the new equilibrium position but are still equal.

Comment: Thanks I got it now

Comment: Please always include a proper citation when you quote a source.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The equilibrium constant is just that i.e. constant (at a given temperature), thus if $A=B$ then $K=[A]/[B]$ so if A increases so must B.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン sorry I am new and still learning

Comment: @porphyrin I was thinking of how to proof that equilibrium constant doesn't get affected by increasing the concentration not the other way around

Comment: Ahmed, the equilibrium constant $K_e$ is the ratio of rate constants and these are determined by the properties of the molecules involved. $K_e= k_1/k_{-1}=[A_e]/[B_e]$ where $k_1$ is for  A forming B and $k_{-1}$ for the back reaction B forming A. The subscript 'e' indicates equilibrium concentrations. Have a look for 'kinetic approach to equilibrium' in a textbook.

Comment: What textbook did you quote from?

Comment: @BuckThorn the textbook of the Egyptian curriculum

Comment: @porphyrin thanks